# How to attach file in TeamCity 8.1 build run dialog?

Tags: teamcity, build-process, attachment, teamcity-8.0

I want to attach some file as option in TeamCity 8.1 Build Run dialog form. 
Before start build this file must be copied into defined place on the Agent side.
Who knows, is it possible? I can't find any plugins for it.

Tnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Where does this file normally reside?  ie:  where would TeamCity get it from?
2. Where should this file be copied to on the build agent?  Can it be placed in the sandbox (work folder) for a given project?

If the file is stored in source control, you can specify a VCS root to get it copied over to the sandbox the same way you specify a VCS root to get the source code you wish to build copied to the sandbox.

For our projects, we regularly specify two VCS roots for a single project: one to copy some scripts and utilities our build requires and one to copy the actual source code that needs to be built.

Hope that helps!

Comment: 1. I would like to get it from a user through a dialogue Run, with analog "attach file" option, but could not.


2. And then the file should have been copied to the working directory.


Yes, we specified second VCS root for addition files, it helped, tnx :)